# ReentrantReadWriteLock gets lost—IllegalMonitorStateException is thrown

Tags: java, locking

My progam throws an `IllegalMonitorStateException` when unlocking from inside the `finally` block. Javadoc says that this exception is thrown “if the current thread does not hold this lock”. However, if the program ever reaches the finally block it must have obtained a lock before. The lock isn’t unlocked elsewhere before. Can a lock “get lost”?

Code example:

```
final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void doSomething() {
    Lock lock = rwLock.writeLock();
    try {
        doStuff();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: So the problem comes from not calling `lock.lock()`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue occurs when upgrading from `ReentrantLock` to `ReentrantReadWriteLock` because the semantics of both classes differ. This code works as expected:

```
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void doSomething() {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        doStuff();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The difference is, `lock.lock()` [optionally waits for and then] takes the lock for the current thread as expected, but `rwLock.writeLock()` does only returns the write lock part of the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` instance and doesn’t try to lock anything. As to [this example](http://programmingexamples.wikidot.com/reentrantreadwritelock), the code should look like that:

```
final ReadWriteLock rwLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void doSomething() {
    rwLock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        doStuff();
    } finally {
        rwLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

The getter methods `writeLock()`—and also `readLock()`—return the same lock for the same thread every time, so the obtained lock doesn’t need to be kept in a variable to unlock it later, you can simply obtain “a new one” to unlock “the old one” because they necessarily have to be the same. (This is because `Thread.currentThread()` is static.)